# No toolbar buttons in landscape mode on any tablet

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat

This is for FormsAppCompatActivity.

You can see the buttons on the toolbar just fine in portrait mode:

[image]

Now, in landscape:

[image]

First, the buttons are not there any more. Second, the drawer button becomes an arrow which will actually close the drawer leaving a white gap.

This has to be a bug.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: this is pure xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @VetaLio Xamarin.Forms using the new FormsAppCompatActivity

Comment: hmm,i'm not sure,but seems that you're right(about "bug"). So this this part of menu(hamburger and drawer layout) is implemented by Appcompat or native Master/detail page of Forms?

Comment: Well, the Toolbar is defined by me and then I tell FormsAppCompatActivity to use it. The buttons on the Toolbar are added to the Detail page in the MasterDetailPage the Xamarin.Forms somehow adds that to the Toolbar.

Comment: @VetaLio https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35657

Comment: (cant adres to your nickname,seems that you turn off this feature).So once i implemented on xamarin.Forms masterdetailpage with harmburger icon and etc(worked well on tablet/phone,but that was for iOs and without FormsAppCompat).So i'm not so strong with your problem. Try to write on xamarin.forms thread also!

Comment: Mate, this only happened with new FormsAppCompatActivity. I don't think you tried that before.